# Waiting for Flash Player to Connect to Debugger - FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, debugging, flashdevelop

I tried to trace something but it didn't output it. I don't know why I am getting this error. There's a message in FlashDevelop, in the bottom right corner, after I compile, it says

> "Waiting for Flash Player to Connect to Debugger"

and there's a loading bar next to it, besides taking quite some time to load, in the end it outputs:

> [No debug Flash player connection request]

EDIT: I opened FD and the debugger was working. Whenever it's not tracing or showing errors I restart and it works. Don't know what it is although doesn't seem vital since I can restart

Comment: Most likely you need to install the debug version of the Flash Player for the browser you're testing in: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: I just now read your comment. I'll check it but what is the relation? I mean, I'm using FlashDevelop, AS3 language with Box2D library. The compiler is flex thingy. AFAIK I'm not testing it with any browser at all :P

Comment: The debugger is "FlashPlayerDebugger" which was installed with flex "flex\runtimes\player\11.1\win\FlashPlayerDebugger"